# How can I create a document with bilingual headings and table of contents in KOMAScript?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, koma-script, languages, multilingual

I am writing a book and so far it has been completely in English. Now as a convenience for, say, German readers I'd like to provide a German translation for every heading and for the table of contents.
I am envisioning two things:

1. being able to write `\bichapter{engl. header}{ger. header}` and `\bisection{engl. header}{ger. header}` throughout the document. For example when I write `\bichapter{Introduction}{Einleitung}`, I'd like that to typeset

   ```
   1. Introduction
      Einleitung [e.g., in gray font]
   ```
2. having two table of contents, one that contains all English headers and another one that contains all German headers, where all PDF hyperref links link  exactly to the header as typeset in point #1.

Below is a minimal "non-working" example that describes my envisioned flow of LaTeX commands:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}

\NewDocumentCommand\bichapter{mm}{%
    \chapter{#1}
    \addtocounter{chapter}{-1}%
    {\let\clearpage\relax\let\addtotoc\relax\chapter{\selectlanguage{ngerman}#2}}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand\bisection{mm}{%
    \section{#1}%
    \addtocounter{section}{-1}%
    {\let\clearpage\relax\let\addtotoc\relax\section{\selectlanguage{ngerman}#2}}%
}

\begin{document}
    \selectlanguage{english}\tableofcontents
    \selectlanguage{ngerman}\tableofcontents
    \selectlanguage{english}
    
    \bichapter{Introduction}{Einleitung}
        \bisection{History}{Historie}
        \bisection{Objective}{Ziel}
    \bichapter{Acquisition of Data}{Datenerhebung}
    \bichapter{Conclusion}{Fazit}
\end{document}
```

The output of the above MWE looks as follows:

[image]
[image]

You see that English and German headers are intermingled in the English table of contents (while the German table of contents is completely empty anyway).

### Related Work

I've seen people patch `\chapter`, `\section`, and `\tableofcontents` commands of the `article` document class [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/300178/38074) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/312260/38074). To my novice eyes, the corresponding definitions in `scrbook` look considerably more complicated and I have no expertise in patching them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With KOMA-Script you can simply define a new ToC using `\DeclareNewTOC` and write the German entries to that new ToC:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman,main=english]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{german}{gray}

\DeclareNewTOC[listname=\contentsname]{gtoc}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\tableofgermancontents}{%
  \begingroup
    \selectlanguage{ngerman}%
    \let\if@dynlist\if@tocleft% This is only needed, if you want to be able to
                              % use option toc=flat.
    \listoftoc{gtoc}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\NewDocumentCommand\bichapter{O{#2}mO{#4}m}{%
  \chapter[#1]{#2\hfil\linebreak\foreignlanguage{ngerman}{\textcolor{german}{#4}}}%
  \addxcontentsline{gtoc}{chapter}[\thechapter]{\foreignlanguage{ngerman}{#3}}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand\bisection{O{#2}mO{#4}m}{%
  \section[#1]{#2\hfil\linebreak\foreignlanguage{ngerman}{\textcolor{german}{#4}}}%
  \addxcontentsline{gtoc}{section}[\thesection]{\foreignlanguage{ngerman}{#3}}%
}

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \tableofgermancontents
    
  \bichapter{Introduction}{Einleitung}
  \bisection{History}{Historie}
  \bisection{Objective}{Ziel}
  \bichapter{Acquisition of Data}{Datenerhebung}
  \bichapter{Conclusion}{Fazit}

  \bichapter[Head and table of contents]{Chapter title}[Kopf und Inhaltsverzeichnis]{Überschrift}
\end{document}
```

[image: Contents]

[image: Inhaltsverzeichnis]

[image: Introduction/Einleitung, History/Historie, Objective/Ziel]

Another suggestion would be, to extend the optional argument of `\chapter`, `\section` etc. by an option for the German title and then redefine `\addchaptertocentry` and `\chapterlineformat` and maybe `\chaptermark` to use the value of the new option. But this would be more complicated and you've explicitly asked for a solution using `\bichapter` and `\bisection` (instead of `\chapter` and `\section`).